# Can AMP get access to DOM element?

Tags: amp-html

I'm using amp-analytics to track user behaviors like click, I understand that I can specify the element under "selector" by using its CSS identifier (like class, id) or add data-vars-* attribute on each element that I want to track click for and track a group of elements. However, is there a better way to track clicks more dynamically, like the onClick event listener for DOM element instead of adding more attribute on the elements? Thanks.

And I have a follow up question, if AMP can't get access to DOM element, does that mean AMP can't read cookies from document.cookie? If can, how? And how does AMP handle GDPR problem? Thanks.